# Another Word Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I move faster than one can blink,
And can be the base of what you eat.
I can torture body and wallet both,
while in feet, I am reused.
When living, I am the source of much food,
and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

What am I?

Hint

> For a shop I am the definition of good.

Answer

> Stock

Explanation

> I move faster than one can blink, - Stocks change price and owners incredibly fast.
>  And can be the base of what you eat. - Soup Stock
>  I can torture body and wallet both, - Stocks are a medieval torture device, and the stock market has ruined many
>  while in feet, I am reused. - Stock Footage
>  When living, I am the source of much food, - Livestock
>  and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.
> For a shop I am the definition of good. - A shop's stocks is goods, by definition

Comment: I can't answer it but I might have and idea, to prevent any spoiler I will only talk about this line "When living, I am the source of much food", is it because is living form is a tree ?

Comment: Since no one has found it yet, let me add another hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:

> Stock

I move faster than one can blink,

> You're stock of goods can sell off the shelves very quickly

And can be the base of what you eat.

> You can stockpile food to be your main source of nutrition

I can torture body and wallet both,

> Medieval Stocks were torture devices and you can lose a lot of money in the stock market.

while in feet, I am reused.

> Stockings is plural

When living, I am the source of much food,

> Livestock like cows and pigs are our sources of meat

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> The stock of a gun is placed in the crux of the shoulder which is near the heart when firing

And the hint

> High stock prices are the definition of a successful publicly owned company

Comment: Finally. I was starting to worry I'd made it too difficult.

Comment: The hint helps a lot

Comment: I thought it might be this, but I couldn't figure out the "move faster" or "soldier" parts.

Answer (score 8):

Are you

> Energy? (E)

I move faster than one can blink,

> Energy is light, and light moves fast, like really fast. E = MC^2

And can be the base of what you eat.

> We eat to restore our energy.

I can torture body and wallet both,

> Lack of energy is tiring. If we don't use energy to work, we won't have any money.

while in feet, I am reused.

> **e** is reused in f**ee**t

When living, I am the source of much food,

> Energy is required for plants and animals to grow.

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> Energy is life, and their lives are on the line, which they would hold close to their hearts.

Comment: I suspect the third line may be referencing something else denoted by the same letter (maybe the first line too?), and I wonder whether the last line is merely positional wordplay.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're a

> plate

I move faster than one can blink

> A frisbee can be a form of a plate

And can be the base of what you eat

> Who will doubt this?

I can torture body and wallet both

> So true, especially if you go to the restaurant

while in feet, I am reused.

> [Footplate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footplate)

When living, I am the source of much food,

> I think of you more as a presenter than a source

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> Military name plate

Comment: I didn't expect that one. However, like you said, it isn't a source of food. Your way of thinking is getting closer to the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be:

> Blood

**Reasoning:**

I move faster than one can blink,

> Blood is pumped pretty quickly

And can be the base of what you eat.

> Blood is found cooked in meat, or blood sausage

I can torture body and wallet both,

> Torture causes lots of blood. A blood transfusion costs lots of money.

while in feet, I am reused.

> The blood circulates and is reused.

When living, I am the source of much food,

> It transports oxygen and nutrients (food) to your cells

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> As close as it gets, since the blood enters the heart

Comment: I like, but wrong. Blood is not reused only in feet.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

> Carbon

**Reasoning:**

I move faster than one can blink,

> Carbon molecules vibrate very quickly

And can be the base of what you eat.

> It's present in pretty much all food

I can torture body and wallet both,

> Carbon dioxide and many other chemicals containing Carbon can be detrimental to your health or used for torture, and the gas emissions cost the economy much money.

while in feet, I am reused.

> Your body's cells are Carbon-based and are re-used until they die.

When living, I am the source of much food,

> Most (all?) food is Carbon-based

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> Carbon in the dirt, Carbon in their clothes and in their bodies, in their weapons, etc.

Comment: Same as your other answer. Carbon doesn't have anything special in feet.

Comment: It doesn't have to be special. It just has to fit.

Comment: Indeed, it has to fit. In feet specially. If not, why specify?

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Light

1. > Light travels faster than blink
2. > Plants use light to make food via photosynthesis
3. > Not sure
4. > Light is covered to heat via heating pads to heat feet while in col
5. > Mentioned in point 2
6. > Not sure

Comment: Nope. Good try, but it's something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

My second try
Can it be

> Smoke

1. > smoke moves faster than blink

2.

> Smoke is used to cook out food

3.

> Fire produces smoke which is kind of torture to the body and in order to repair stuff it is hit to our wallet

4.

> smoke is used to provide heat to feet in form of steam

5.

> When wood we cook food which turns into smoke

6.

> not sure

Comment: Still not in feet.

Answer (score 0):

> Pellets

I move faster than one can blink,

> gun pellets

And can be the base of what you eat.

> food pellets

I can torture body and wallet both,

> gun pellets can hurt and also be expensive

while in feet, I am reused.

> rubber pellets used in shoes

When living, I am the source of much food,

> wood pellets from a tree; the tree is a source of food

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> gun pellets again

Comment: Nope. As a hint, this riddle has the wordplay tag for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

What am I?

> information

I move faster than one can blink,

> It has

And can be the base of what you eat.

> only after knowing can anything be processed, {you bite only when you know you've got to, if you forget}

I can torture body and wallet both,

> banks, how to make money, how to steal money, how to kill a goof

while in feet, I am reused.

> poetry

When living, I am the source of much food,

> gotta know how to take that shit

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> brainwashing

Answer (score 0):

can it be

> fish

move faster than one can blink,

> fish move quite fast.

And can be the base of what you eat.

> used in food

I can torture body and wallet both,

> dangerous fish can torture body, expensive food fish can torture wallet.

while in feet, I am reused.

> fish are used for fish feet massage. reused there.

When living, I am the source of much food,

> again, used for food.

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> maybe something related to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_(cryptography))

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's :

> Water

I move faster than one can blink,

> Water travels faster then you can blink

And can be the base of what you eat.

> You basically need water for everything and it's in everything.

I can torture body and wallet both,

> You can drown in water, staying to long in water can torture you. Wallet, because you need to buy water

while in feet, I am reused.

> Cleaning your dirty feet with water?

When living, I am the source of much food,

> You need water to cook.

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> Their water bottle

Answer (score 0):

Could it be

> Lash

I move faster than one can blink,

> Your lashes will go faster than your eyelid if you blink

And can be the base of what you eat.

> Don't know

I can torture body and wallet both,

> To lash someone, to lash out

while in feet, I am reused.

> Don't know

When living, I am the source of much food,

> Don't know

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> Don't know

Even if I didn't find many things, I have the feeling that it could be the right answer, considering the "wordplay" tag

Comment: EDIT : answer changed, but few ideas for the sentences, even though I have the feeling the two I found seem to fit really well with their line

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly correct but here is my guess:

> Tongue or mouth and lips

I move faster than one can blink,

> Quite fast while moving not sure how fast, though

And can be the base of what you eat.

> Anything eaten has to be put in mouth or tongue

I can torture body and wallet both,

> all of them can torture body if you eat too much and definitely the wallet

while in feet, I am reused.

> Not sure about this one

When living, I am the source of much food,

> The gateway to body for food

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts.

> Soldiers kiss their flag and/or badges on their chest

Please help if somebody finds correct explanation for missing or wrong ones. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is my guess

> Heat

reasons:

I move faster than one can blink

> heat can travel faster than one can blink

And can be the base of what you eat.

> heat is the base to cook food. even though fire is used to cook but the food is cooked by the heat of fire

I can torture body and wallet both

> too much heat can torture the body and you spend lot of money to get a cooler enviornment

while in feet, I am reused

> this is a wild guess but by this you must be referring to Burning feet syndrome

When living, I am the source of much food

> food can be cooked only when there is heat. a dead heat is of no use

and soldiers lay me close to their hearts

> soldiers that are in cold environment heat is the only way of survival and hence they have to wear clothes that provide heat

Comment: You can click edit to see how I formatted your answer.